# Can't read values from array if the first position is empty

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop, multidimensional-array, minimum

I have this simple code, the idea is to find the the minimum value out of an array containing numbers, it works, most of the time:

```
For yy As Integer = 0 To 23
 If (IsNumeric(data(2, yy))) Then
  If (yy > 0) Then
   If (data(2, yy) < min(days)) Then
    min(days) = data(2, yy)
   End If
  Else
   min(days) = data(2, yy)
  End If
 End If
Next
```

Now, the data array may or may not contain values, the code has no problem working when the first position in the array has a value, even if other positions in the array are empty. The problem is when the first position of the array is empty, even if the rest of the array is full of values, it wont read any of them, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scenario, in the first loop you set `min(days)` to zero.
Then in the subsequent loop (yy=1 etc...) you check the value contained in `data(2, yy)` with the same `min(days)` that you have set to zero in the first loop.

Thus you never get a true condition for the  `if(data(2,yy) < min(days)` unless data(2,yy) is less than zero

It seems that you have something wrong because you use always the same value `min(days)`

Comment: Oh you are right, how silly of me, when yy=1 it would automatically compare if data(2,yy) was less than min(days), and it would never be because min(days) had 0 by default as value.

Answer (score 1):

If the first element is empty, then you never get into the `Else` part where you set `min(days)` to an initial value. Hence `min(days)` is the default value `0`. And I assume that `0` is always smaller than every number in `days(2, yy)`.

What about Linq to do the job?

```
    min(days) = (From index1 In {2}
                 From index2 In Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
                 Where IsNumeric(data(index1, index2))
                 Select (data(index1, index2))).Min()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check beforehand to find where to start in the array (n.b. not tested against your code):

```
Dim startAt As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To 23
    If IsNumeric(data(2, i)) Then
        startAt = i
        min(days) = data(2, i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For i As Integer = startAt + 1 To 23
    If (IsNumeric(data(2, i))) Then
        If (data(2, i) < min(days)) Then
            min(days) = data(2, i)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

However, I suspect that you need to set [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your project and work through a lot of datatype problems.